# Durable map to map to queue for fair scheduling?

Tags: java, dictionary, queue

Our system needs to process billions of queries from thousands of clients for millions of resources. Some resources will be queried much more often than others. Each client will submit anywhere from hundreds to hundreds-of-millions of queries at a time. Because each resource can only support thousands of queries per minute, the queries will be enqueued and their results will be determined asynchronously.

Now, here's the rub: Each client's queries need to be given equal priority with respect to each resource. That is, if one client submits a million queries for a particular resource, and then another client submits a dozen, immediately after, then the second client should not have to wait for the first client's queries to be processed before theirs are. Rather, first the one client's first query should be handled, and then the other's first query, then the first's second query, and so on, back and forth. (And the analogous idea for more than two clients, and multiple resources; also, it can be a little less granular, as long as this basic idea is preserved).

If this was small enough to be in-memory, we'd just have a map from resources to a map from accounts to a queue of queries, and circularly iterate accounts, per resource; but it's not, so we need a disk-based solution. We also need it to be robust, highly available, transactional *etc.*. What are my options? I'm using Java SE.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your question about how to implement the queueing of requests or how to implement the database being queried?  Or both?

Comment: If I can avoid a database, entirely (*e.g.* MapReduce? Gearman?) that would be ideal. This is just a component of the system, not the system itself, so I don't want to spend an inordinate amount of time on it.

Comment: By your retrieval logic (resource-first, account-second (timestamp-third)), it seems like someone with account-id 1 would always have their queries processed before someone with account-id 2.  Shouldn't it resource-first, timestamp-second, with no accounting for account id right?

Comment: Thinking about it further, you need to keep track of which account id's have any outstanding requests (at all) for a given resource so that you know whose query to go and get next.  Otherwise you need to rely on insertion time (which you said you didn't want), or account id (which as I point out above is inherently unfair) or some other metric.

Comment: 1. Sorry, I meant to say (as in the question) that the ordering needs to be resource-first, then *round-robin* for accounts, then timestamp. 2. The way we've defined "fair" above is not FIFO. 3. If we have a proper map abstraction, then we know which account IDs have outstanding requests by iterating over the keys (but I will solve this out-of-band, if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Ahead of time, I know HBase much better than I do Cassandra.  Some aspects of my response are HBase specific, and I'll mark them as such.

Assuming that you provision enough hardware, then a BigTable implementation like Cassandra or HBase would give you the following:

1. The ability to store and retrieve your queries at an extremely high rate
2. The ability to absorb deletes at an extremely high rate (though with HBase and Cassandra, flushing writes to disk can cause periodic delays)

Trivially, I could see a schema where you used a combination of resource-id as row key and account-id and perhaps timestamp as column key, but (in HBase specifically) this could lead to hotspots in the servers hosting certain popular resources (in both HBase and Cassandra, a single server is responsible for hosting the master copy of any given row at a time).  In Cassandra you can reduce the overhead of updates by using async writes (writing to only one or two nodes, and allowing gossip to replicate them), but this could result in old records being around dramatically longer than you expect in situations where network traffic is high.  In HBase writes are always consistent and always written to the RegionServer hosting the row, so hotspotting is definitely a potential problem.

You can reduce the impact of hotspotting by making your row key a combination of resource ID and account id, but then you need to scan all row keys to determine the list of accounts that have outstanding queries for a resource.

One other potential advantage that you may not have considered is the potential capability to run your queries directly from the HBase or Cassandra data nodes, saving you the need to ship your query over the network again to an executor process to actually run that query.  You might want to look into [HBase Coprocessors](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-2000) or [Cassandra Plugins](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1016) to do something like that.  Specifically I am talking about turning this workflow:

```
                                 /-> Query -> Executor -> Resource -> Results -> \
Client -> Query -> Query Storage --> Query -> Executor -> Resource -> Results -> --> Client
                                 \-> Query -> Executor -> Resource -> Results -> /
```

into something like:

```
                                 /-> Query -> Resource -> Results -> \
Client -> Query -> Query Storage --> Query -> Resource -> Results -> --> Client
                                 \-> Query -> Resource -> Results -> /
```

This may not make sense in your use case though.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some answers with respect to Cassandra.

Cassandra internally writes only new data files and only does so sequentially, never overwriting or modifying existing files, and has an append-only write-ahead log like transactional relational databases. Cassandra internally sees deletes as essentially just like any other writes.

Cassandra is linearly scalable across many nodes and has no single point of failure. It is linearly scalable for both reads and writes. That is to say, a single cluster can support any number of concurrent reads and writes you wish to throw at it, so long as you add enough nodes to the cluster and give the cluster time to rebalance data across the new nodes. Netflix recently [load-tested Cassandra on EC2](http://techblog.netflix.com/2011/11/benchmarking-cassandra-scalability-on.html) and found linear scalability, with the largest cluster they tested at 288 nodes supporting 1,000,000 writes/sec sustained for an hour.

Cassandra supports [many consistency levels](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API). When performing each read or write from Cassandra, you specify with what consistency level you want that read or write to be executed. This lets you determine, per-read and per-write, whether that read or write must be fast or must be done consistently across all nodes hosting that row.

Cassandra does not support multi-operation transactions.

If the Cassandra data model works well in your case, Cassandra may well be the simplest solution, at least at the operations level. Every node is configured exactly alike. There are no masters and no slaves, only peers of equals. It is not necessary to set up separate load balancing, failover, heartbeats, log shipping, replication, etc.

But the only way to find out for sure is to test it out.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but can you please address my question more directly? I am aware that Cassandra is scaleable and robust, and these are strong points in its favor. My question is more as to whether it is a sensible choice to solve this single problem (and if so, with what caveats, *etc.*), and otherwise, what might be a better solution?